# How to solve this issue: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, plaid

I get an error message like the one below when I run the command `composer require tomorrow-ideas/plaid-sdk-php`.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - tomorrow-ideas/plaid-sdk-php[1.0, ..., 1.0.9] require nimbly/shuttle ^0.4 -> satisfiable by nimbly/shuttle[0.4].
    - nimbly/shuttle 0.4 requires nimbly/capsule ^1.0 -> satisfiable by nimbly/capsule[1.0, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
    - nimbly/capsule[1.0, ..., 1.1.2] require psr/http-message ^1.0 -> found psr/http-message[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1] but the package is fixed to 2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires tomorrow-ideas/plaid-sdk-php ^1.0 -> satisfiable by tomorrow-ideas/plaid-sdk-php[1.0, ..., 1.0.9].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require tomorrow-ideas/plaid-sdk-php:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require tomorrow-ideas/plaid-sdk-php:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

How to solve this issue?
Note: I'm using Laravel 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I added the record in the composer.json file and then ran the composer update command.

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "tomorrow-ideas/plaid-sdk-php": "^1.0"
},
```